# How to get the rest of text content based of text selection on UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

I want to get the remaining text contents from the text element users select on UIWebView.

For example, let's say there is html like this.

```
<div class="entry">
<p>paragraph 1 blaa</p>
<p>paragraph 2 blaa<a href="http://someadddress"> rest of blaa</p>
<p>paragraph 3 blaa</p>
<p>paragraph 4 blaa</p>
</div>
```

- **My Goal**

once User click the text of paragraph 2, I want to get the rest of the text contents which 
means paragraph2 and paragraph 3 and paragraph 4 without paragraph 1.

I wrote the following code in -(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender

```
NSLog(@"%@",[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"(window.getSelection()).anchorNode.textContent"
```

**- the first problem.**

If users select paragraph 2, I can get only "paragraph 2 blaa" but can't get "the rest of blaa" part inside of the element because of link part.

**- the second problem.**

I can't get next Sibling textContent by this code.

```
NSLog(@"%@",[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"(window.getSelection()).anchorNode.nextSibling.textContent"
```

I would really appreciate for any suggestions!